# For using a private domain in sender's profile in FROM, is there any need to create a mailbox?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, reply-mail-management

**Background:** We have recently added a private domain like sub.domain.com to our SFMC account (this private domain is in addition to what we already have in SAP). One of the requirement for Salesforce team to configure private domain in SFMC is to delegate the domain where we updates the nameservers and pointed to what Salesforce requested.

**Next step,** to my knowledge is going to be the following:

- Setup Senders Profile (for new private domain - sub.domain.com)
- Setup RMM (for new private domain - sub.domain.com)

Considering, within Senders profile we define the FROM email address and in this case it will be something like:

- email@sub.domain.com

**Question:**

1. Is there any need to create a mailbox first for "email@sub.domain.com" (which require us to work with our internal IT)? OR we can put anything in FROM email address (in other words - anything before @ of the private domain)?
2. Where do we configure reply-to email address? in Senders profile OR RMM?
   Does reply-to email address needs to be configured as a mailbox first? assuming yes, so it can receive email but just confirming.
3. When we configure RMM and IF we forward reply to any email address? the forward email address needs to be a valid mailbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a working inbox corresponding to your from address. Most probably you don't even have your own MX records created for *sub.domain.com*, as these normally point to the servers of Salesforce Marketing Cloud (for the purpose of RMM). Hence you will never be able to route the replies directly to your own email servers.

There are exceptions, especially when sending from your TLD, e.g. using john.doe@example.com, as in this case you can't both have MX records pointing to your own email servers (required to allow John receive his emails) and MX records pointing to SFMC (required for RMM). In this case, you will need to self-host your DNS, and only add DKIM/SPF/DMARC records authenticating the IP address of SFMC to send emails on behalf of example.com.

Only if you configure RMM, you will need a real inbox, as the emails forwarded by RMM will need to go somewhere. It can be any email address on any domain, and not necessary same domain as the one used as your SAP/Private Domain in SFMC.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas